# Calling variables located in a method of another class (Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I am a beginner at this, so I appreciate your patience and understanding with regards to the problem I have got.

**Background**

What I am using: macOS, Python3, ATOM

I am trying to build a library that stores information on books available (Title, Author, Year, ISBN). My plan for this is to create a script for backend and frontend separately. Ultimately connecting it all on the frontend script through importing the backend script and using the functions designed there. And yes, I have used OOP before but only for building a blackjack game. tkinter's usage of class is kinda wack for me and I got lost.

**Current Situation**

I have the UI looking just the way I want it to and am currently creating functions to be used for commands attached to buttons. The issue is, I have the entry widget and the ScrolledText widget in two different classes representing two different frames (Top and Bottom) and while calling for the variable

```
title.val = tk.StringVar()
```

an error popped up:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  /LIBfront.py", line 105, in <module>
    class main():
  /LIBfront.py", line 111, in main bottomleft = BottomFrame(win)
  /LIBfront.py", line 52, in __init__ self.search_cmd()
  /LIBfront.py", line 64, in search_cmd for row in LIBback.search_entry(TopFrame.title_val.get(), self.author_val.get(), year_val.get(), isbn_val.get()):
AttributeError: type object 'TopFrame' has no attribute 'title_val'
```

Here is a reduced version of the code, containing only one of the sections. **EDIT: changes done based on feedback**

```
    import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import LIBback # This is just the backend script

# Creating top frame for user input
class TopFrame():

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win
        self.frame = tk.Frame(win, relief = 'groove')
        self.frame.pack(fill = 'x', expand = False)
        self.topwidgets()

    def topwidgets(self):
        self.title_val = tk.StringVar()
        self.lbl1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Title:')
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, width = 25, textvariable = self.title_val)
        self.lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, ipadx = 10, ipady = 10)
        self.e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'e')

# Creating bottom frame for user interaction and results display
class BottomFrame():

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(win)
        self.frame1.pack(fill = 'both', side = "left", expand = False)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(win)
        self.frame2.pack(fill = 'both', side = "left", expand = True)
        self.widgets()
        self.search_cmd()

    def search_cmd(self):
        self.txtbox.delete('1.0',tk.END) # Below this line is where the issue began
        for row in LIBback.search_entry(self.title_val.get()):
            self.txtbox.insert(tk.END, row)

    def widgets(self):
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = 'Search Entry', height = 2 , width = 10, command = self.search_cmd)
        self.button2.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'y', pady = 5, padx = 5)

def main():
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('Book Shop')
    win.geometry("630x370")
    top = TopFrame(win)
    bottom = BottomFrame(top)
    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**What I have tried or tried to understand**

1. The variable of interest is not declared as an attribute even though the method is declared and using that variable.
2. Accessing it through TopFrame.topwidgets.title_val.get(), in the form of [CLASS.FUNCTION.VAR.get()] did not work for me.
3. Mimicking other examples of OOP using tkinter whereby there is a 'master'? class, and declaring self.var = tk.StringVar() there and using a 'controller' to refer to it. Failed due to my lack of understanding in doing it that way.

**My Question**

How do I, in this case, call on that variable? and possibly, can you walk me through the process as to why it failed to declare it as an attribute of the class or how I failed to make them connect to each other?

Thank you very much for your help in advance! Really appreciate it!

Comment: First `title_val` is a local variable inside `topwidgets()` and so it cannot be accessed outside this function, even in other functions of `TopFrame`.  Change it to instance variable `self.title_val`.  Second you cannot use class `TopFrame` to access the variable, you should use instance of `TopFrame`, i.e. `top` inside `main()` instead.  However, `top` is also a local variable inside `main()` (Should `main()` be a function instead of class?), so it cannot be accessed outside the function as well.  Suggest to pass `top` to `BottomFrame` when creating `bottom` inside `main()`.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 ! You have pointed out a really crucial mistake on my `main()` being a class instead of a function, I have since fixed it and it makes more sense! I have also changed the variables into an instance variable by attaching a `self.` in front of it, as well as attaching that `self.` to when I am calling the function in `button2`. However, I am still unsure as to how to call it. I tried passing `top` to `BottomFrame` as you suggested, and it returned `AttributeError: 'TopFrame' object has no attribute 'tk'`. Mind explaining further on calling the variable as well as the last part?

Comment: Please update your code with the changes.

Comment: @acw1668, I have just updated it! Thank you for your patience. As mentioned, I have added `self.` to both the variable and the function when I call them. Under `main()` I have also passed top into the `BottomFrame()` argument along with changing `main()` into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `top` as an argument to `BottomFrame` so that `title_val` inside `TopFrame` can be accessed inside `BottomFrame`:

```
class BottomFrame():
    def __init__(self, win, top):
        self.win = win
        self.top = top
        ...

    def search_cmd(self):
        self.txtbox.delete('1.0',tk.END)
        for row in LIBback.search_entry(self.top.title_val.get()):
            self.txtbox.insert(tk.END, row)

...

def main():
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('Book Shop')
    win.geometry("630x370")
    top = TopFrame(win)
    bottom = BottomFrame(win, top) # pass top to BottomFrame
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm now and I have learnt a lot as to how I can use the variables from different classes!